# How to connect to heroku postgresql from dart app?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, dart

I host my dart server in heroku. I provisioned [heroku postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/heroku-postgres) for this app.
I referenced the library [postgres](https://pub.dev/packages/postgres) to access the data.

In this library the constructor for object PostgreSQLConnection requires three parameters: url, port and db name.

Heroku gives me just one connection string.
I tried to pass different parts of this string to the constructor, but it failed:

`SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'postgres://isbmdx...`

This is my code:

```
import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';

class DataAccess {
  static Future<Object> ProcessRequest() async {
    var valueFromHeroku =
        Platform.environment["DATABASE_URL"];

    var dbPort = 5432;
    var dbName = "d8hqb682glgsf0";

    var connection = PostgreSQLConnection(valueFromHeroku, dbPort, dbName);
    await connection.open();

    ...
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give a more detailed example of how you use the postgress library to make the connection. Also an example of the string you mention in "Heroku gives me just one connection string".

Comment: I added the details to the question

Comment: You hostname are a lot more complicated than the example on https://pub.dev/packages/postgres (e.g. you have the postgres:// prefix). Have you tried to connect like the example on the package page?

Comment: Yes, it is more complicated. Do you know how to extract the host name from the connection string, provided by Heroku?

Comment: Well, the hostname from your example whould be "ec2-107-21-216-112.compute-1.amazonaws.com".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the connection string provided via DATABASE_URL in heroku is the following:

```
postgres://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@<DATABASE_HOST>:<PORT>/<DATABASE_NAME>
```

This is how the string can be parsed in dart:

```
class PostgresInstance {
  final String host;
  final int port;
  final String database;
  final String user;
  final String password;

  PostgresInstance(
      this.host, this.port, this.database, this.user, this.password);

  factory PostgresInstance.fromString(String connectionString) {
    RegExp pattern = RegExp(
        "^postgres:\\\/\\\/(?<user>[^:]*):(?<pass>[^@]*)@(?<host>[^:]*):(?<port>[^\\\/]*)\\\/(?<db>[^\/]*)\$");
    RegExpMatch match = pattern.firstMatch(connectionString);
    if (match == null)
      throw Exception("Could not parse Postgres connection string.");
    int port = int.parse(match.namedGroup('port'));

    return PostgresInstance(
      match.namedGroup('host'),
      port,
      match.namedGroup('db'),
      match.namedGroup('user'),
      match.namedGroup('pass'),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the test to validate correctness:

```
  test('Parse connection string', () async {
    String conn = "postgres://user:password@a.bc.d:5555/db";
    PostgresInstance i = PostgresInstance.fromString(conn);
    expect(i.host, "a.bc.d");
    expect(i.port, 5555);
    expect(i.database, "db");
    expect(i.password, "password");
    expect(i.user, "user");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You try using external props and configure in cloud web console  like as DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a your-app) your_process

Comment: It gives me just one value, while I need three to setup connection.